# Language Identification

Tags: c, unicode

I'm thinking of doing a language identification program using C language. I already searched in the internet and found the N-Gram-Based Text Categorization article, and I also created my own set of utilities to handle some of my programming needs. Now, I would like to try first creating a simple program that printf japanese word, written in hiragana, katakana, and kanji. I believed this can be done in C language, but I'm not sure on how to implement it, maybe this is related to unicode programming. Can anyone try to explain to me what I need to learn first, what library(/ies) I need to #include, or what utilities can be use as my basis of doing and implementing this program.

Comment: This sounds like it's a bit out of your reach, experience-wise.

Comment: Why have you choose C for that task?

Comment: @ThomasMore, just for fun and experience.

Comment: Mike's right, before trying to categorize/indentify/... first get used to charsets, how to identify them, how you can manipulate streams in C (which is basically charset agnostic), what happens if you write a simple console app and test it in a console configured with utf-8 input, another one with shift-jis, UCS2 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think C is the best choice for this project. IMO you should look into using higher level languages (like C#) which have some phenomenal built in support, just a quick example:

C#:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0xE8, 0x82, 0xB2, 0xE5, 0x84, 0xBF }; 
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Boom. Done.

Now in C, to the best of my knowledge, there's no simple standard encoding/decoding libraries or utilities. You'll have to create this stuff by hand. I started doing that at one point myself, but realized it was a waste of my time. :)

If you insist on C, I would suggest you start by reading everything about different types of encodings (multibyte/widebyte encoding). There's lots of good tutorials on [Unicode](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html) around the web to get you started (here's a [good one](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) I used).

EDIT: OK, if no C#, then let's take a "short" example in C... again, this assumes you know something about encoding (note the use of the wide char: wchar_t):

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma import(__use_utf8_ctype)
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  wchar_t water = 27750;
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  printf("%lc",water);
  return 0;
}

mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
汦
```

That's Chinese... I think it's the same Kanji, but I'm not great with Japanese... 
There is how you can print, now storing works similar, you'll store in a wchar_t, then do your comparisons.

Comment: very short implementation, and that is great. yet one thing that impede me to do that is that my box is linux, and I believe C# is part of the .NET frameworks. Thanks anyway!

Comment: IMHO the OP was asking for a classifier, not for a way to convert (iconv on linux) between representations / encodings / charsets.

Comment: @chrismsawi .NET (except the pure ms part) and linux mix well with [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: @wildplasser - I guess I was reading this: `I would like to try first creating a simple program that printf japanese word` as a "trying to start anyplace" type message. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: @Mike: hey! I just tried your's and it worked... So meaning I need to find out the list of utf numbers, and then declare them as wchar_t, then boom! thanks!

Comment: @chrismsawi - Glad it was helpful. I update the answer with a second link that should help (shows use of `setlocale()`. If this is good for you for now don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so people know this issue is closed. (click the gray check mark under the number by the answer)

Comment: @Mike: you gave the right article that I need! exactly for my box! thanks!